# Creating a custom context menu in Qt

Tags: drop-down-menu, menu, qt4

I'd like to create a special context menu for my application.
The menu may have different shape and behaviour from the standard context menu.

For example I'd like to draw them circle-shaped or with ability to right-click on a menu entry, to open another menu *about* that menu item.

Of course, I'd like to integrate them as much as possible with the current framework, that is having action-based menu and such (but I'm not sure about what properties should have a menu to "fit" in the Qt framework).

So, my question is, where should I start to implement this?
I see QMenu inherits from QWidget, so is it just sufficient to implement a custom QWidget for it? Should I instead inherit QMenu and extend it with custom graphics and event handling?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I think you're asking a lot of `QMenu` to customize it so much. I'd recommend just making your own class that derives from `QWidget` and sets it's clipping bitmap (`QWidget::setMask`) and implement the `paintEvent` yourself. It'd probably be better to derive from `QAbstractButton` or `QPushButton` to get button press handling. QActions aren't going to buy you much here.

Comment: But in this way I could not insert, for example, my custom menu as a sub-menu of a regular QMenu, right? For example, what if I want to add a palette selector to an existing QMenu?

Comment: Do you mean have a palette selector pop out when hovering over a menu item as though it were a sub menu?

Comment: Yes, I thought about using QWidgetAction for that. I wonder if it's possible to use QWidgetAction also for doing a menu about the menu as I was saying above.