# Custom shaped menu with shadow in Qt

Tags: qt, mask

I'd like to create a context menu looking similar to this one:
[image]

I read suggestions on the web that `QWidget::setMask()` should be used to create a shape. But how can it fit the variable number of items then? Moreover, the same menu item may take more or less screen space on different machines.

Another question is how to create a shadow around this custom shape? As far as I understand, the mask allows to crop the widget, but not to make it semi-transparent.

Comment: Please provide the source that headed you toward setMask(). And: if items come in variable number,  when and why are they loaded inside the menu? Can you provide some code (i.e. the context menu context)?

Comment: No code exists so far, but let's say I am not sure how many items will be there or I want to consider the possibility of adding new items in future. 

The links:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14490748/creating-a-custom-context-menu-in-qt

http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/50006-Context-Menu-for-Tree-View-with-a-custom-shaped

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show [the code you have so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include at least an outline (but preferably a [mcve]) of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 1):

I don’t found an easy way to do that! But here goes a way!

Instead of using the Qt mask API, I've used a frame-less widget with transparency enabled!

To draw the shadow, I've used radial gradient!

You can change the size of the menu before opening it, however you can’t resize it after opened (for example resize with mouse).

It’s quite easy add or remove widgets, just respect the layout margin to not draw outside the bounds destined to widgets. To simplify your life I created an inherited class of `QPushButton` with colors you can easily customize with style sheet.

See the result:

[image: Example]

You can browse the [source](https://github.com/antonypro/StackOverflow/tree/master/ContextMenu)

Hope that helps!

Comment: While this might be a valuable hint to solve the problem, a good answer also demonstrates the solution.  Please [edit] to provide example code to show what you mean. Alternatively, consider writing this as a comment instead.